# Parsing Java Method Argument

Tags: java, parsing, methods

I want to parse the Java Method Arguments (parameters)
(E.g I have a String )

```
"leftPad(abc,[1,2,3],xyz)"
```

I want it to split and return 3 values in array

```
[abc,[1,2,3],xyz]
```

any ideas how to do it ?
is it possible to have regex for this ?
is there any library available ?

Comment: Whats the use of library here? Just use `return new Object[] {par1, par2, ....};`

Comment: or just return the array itself. come to think of it, why even call that method if all you want to return is something you already have before you call it?

Comment: sorry for the confusion , i have the string and I want to parse the arguments from the string that is inside the round braces ( )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple iteration would work here

```
String str = "abc,[1,2,3],xyz,[1,2,3,4]";
    ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>(); String tmp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '[') {
            tmp = str.substring(i, str.indexOf("]", i+1) + 1);
            i = str.indexOf("]", i+1);
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ',') {
            parts.add(tmp);
            tmp = "";
        } else {
            tmp = tmp + str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    if (!tmp.equals("")) parts.add(tmp);
    System.out.println(parts);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

That very much depends on your requirements.

```
I want to parse the Java Method Arguments (parameters)
(E.g I have a String )
```

Your example string is like super simply Java syntax.

But parameters to a java method can be anything, from a simple literal down to the instantiation of an anonymous inner class!

In other words: if you really have a limited set of possible "input" (like your example), then you can use the other answer and do "low level" parsing manually. But if you consider to work with "all kinds" of possible parameters, then you are simply talking the full width of the java programming language. And then you better get a tool like [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/).